# How is the jet engine inlet danger area affected when airborne?

Tags: engine, jet, inlet

Boeing published engine hazard areas as shown below:

[image: Danger area]

I am curious as to how the danger area is affected when the aircraft is in flight as the jet engine is still vulnerable to foreign object damage.

1. Assuming idle power conditions at 10000 ft (or just airborne in general), are the danger zones the same as on the ground? If not, would there be a way to calculate this?
2. Knowing the danger zone for both idle and full power, would it be possible to calculate the danger zone distance for different power settings? E.g. 50% N1.

Comment: It is doubtful that the area in front of the engines is significant given that the aircraft will probably be outrunning the inlet stream. The area behind the engines will probably combine with the wake of the aircraft, and would probably be difficult to separate the two (or at least not useful since the combined effect is what somebody following the aircraft would be concerned about). If you are asking if something ahead of the aircraft but not directly in the intake stream can get ingested, the answer, I'm guessing, is probably not.

Comment: The "danger zones" that you reference only have meaning when the aircraft is on the ground.  Once you're flying, everything in front of the aircraft is in danger of being either sucked into an engine, or else struck by some part of the aircraft structure. How far in front of the aircraft you'd define this "danger zone" would be based as much on assumed reaction time (to get out of the way of a 200? 300? 400? knot aircraft) as on anything else.  You can't extrapolate the posted figures into anything comparable for "in flight" conditions -- the dangers (to skydivers?) just aren't the same!

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm guessing this would depend on the weight of the object being ingested as well? E.g. a small, light RC plane not positioned directly in the intake stream could still be sucked in if close enough to the engine?

Comment: I think you should precise what you understanding of "danger area". It is primary defined for airport workers on the ground, but as you speak of suction area, you may define what you understand by being in or out of this area.

Comment: Might.  Provided there was anything at 10,000 ft to accidentally ingest other than air.

Comment: @CarloFelicione Bird strikes have been reported at altitudes above 30,000 feet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume the A320 is powered by V2500 engines, one of the options for it. This engine has an air mass flow of [355 kg/s.](https://web.stanford.edu/~cantwell/AA283_Course_Material/GE90_Engine_Data.pdf) At sea level, air density is 1.225kg per cubic m. Hence, 355 kg/s = 355/1.225 = 290 cubic m/s.

Now, let's assume the aircraft is still at sea level, but now at Mach 0.8 (unrealistic, but we'll correct that next). The fan diameter is 1.6 m, which gives an intake area of 2.0 sq.m. Also, Mn 0.8 at 0ft is 272m/s. Hence, every second, the intake sweeps a volume of 272 x 2.0 = 544 cubic m. But, the engine only needs 290 cubic/m of air, per second *assuming air density in the intake is the same as the air surrounding the aircraft*. Therefore, the diameter of a streamline tube of the intake air will actually be smaller than the diameter of the engine inlet. It will be the area that sweeps 290 cubic m/s at 272m/s = 290/272 = 1.07 sq. m., or a diameter of 1.17m, not 1.6m.

Basically, the engine takes the airflow it [wants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Components_of_jet_engines), not what the intake area x forward speed provides. If the engine wants more (such as when the aircraft speed is low, or stationary, but the engine rpm is high, such as at the start of the takeoff roll), the engine will draw air from a large area in front of the engine (as per the max takeoff conditions diagram). Conversely, when the aircraft is at high speed, and the engine throttled back, the intake will spill the excess air it is providing (causing spillage drag).

[image]

Now, let's correct the fact the aircraft can't do Mn 0.8 at sea level. Let's re do the calculation at 35,000ft (10,700m). Here, air density is [0.38 kg per cubic m,](http://www.hochwarth.com/misc/AviationCalculator.html) and pressure and temperature are 3.46 psi and  219 Kelvin (-54C), compared with 14.7psi and 288 Kelvin (15C) at sea level. Thus our 355 kg/s, which is actually a [corrected](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrected_flow) airflow, is a physical (real) air flow of 95.8 kg/s at 35,000ft since theta = 219/288 = 0.76 and delta = 3.46/14.7 = 0.235. Now 95.8 kg/s at 0.38 kg/ cubic m = 252 cubic m per second. Also, Mn 0.8 at 35,000ft is now 237m/s, not 272 as it was at seal level. Hence, every seond the intake area of 2 sq.m is sweeping through 2 x 237 = 474 cubic m per second. But we only want it to sweep 252, hence we need to find the diameter of a streamline tube that will cause this, at 237m/s. Therefore, we need an area of 252/237 = 1.06 sq. m., which occurs with a diameter of 1.16m. This compares with the physical inlet diameter of 1.6m.

Thus, at Mn 0.8, 35,000ft, max power, the green area at the engine intake is now a tube, of 1.16m dia, that extends in front of the aircraft. For how far this extends, depends as suggested, on what reaction time is required for the aircraft to manoeuvre away from an obstacle in this region, or for the object (a bird?) to manoeuvre out of the aircraft's way.

The exact figure of 1.16 is questionable, as the assumption of air density in the intake not changing from the surrounding air is not entirely realistic. But the general result, is I believe, reasonable.

Comment: Should the diameter of the streamline tube at sea level not be 1.17m as opposed to 1.47m? (290/272 = 1.07 sq. m., diameter = 2 * √(1.07/3.14) )

Comment: Would it be correct in saying that if the engine intake diameter is less than the fan diameter (I.e. 1.6m) then the result would be a streamline tube extending in front of the aircraft? And, in the case that the engine intake diameter exceeds the fan diameter (1.6m), then the engine would draw air from a large area like in the diagrams?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake with calculating the diameter from the area. It is a dia of 1.17m, as you say. I have corrected the answer - thanks.

Comment: With regard to your second comment, yes, I would agree in general with what you say.  Note in the first case, the engine doesn't have to suck, so it's not drawing the air in, just swallowing a portion of what the intake provides. In the second case, rather the engine taking air from a cylinder or tube in front of it, it would probably be drawing it from a shape more like a cone or a hemisphere, I expect. Sorry I missed your comments till now. The only odd thing with my answer, is that even in the extreme sea lavel case, the intake seems way oversized.

Comment: This makes sense. However, could the forward distance of this cone/hemisphere be calculated? For example, if the diameter of the cone/hemisphere is 1.1 metres, would the cone/hemisphere also be extending 1.1 metres forward?

Comment: @Zack. I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but hopefully this comment does answer it. If the intake is drawing air from a cone or hemisphere that is 1.1 m dia, at the lip of the intake, how far this area extends forward of the intake depends on how you define the boundary between the air in it, and the surrounding air. If you define the boundary as the air that will enter the intake, compared to an adjacent air particle which will just miss, the area extends forwards forever, if the plane is in forward flight.

Comment: @Zack. If the plane is stationary, you need to define an air velocity which seperates the ambient air from the air entering the engine, as done in the diagrams in the picture of the question.

Comment: I apologise for the lack of clarity. I understand that the area will extend forever and any objects within that area will eventually be ingested by the engine (regardless of whether the engine force is currently acting upon it or not). However, I wanted to see if it was possible to calculate the area where the object would have the engine force acting upon it (the same way that such an area was defined in the original post).

Comment: So for an aircraft currently drawing air from beyond the engine (so air intake diameter is bigger than the engine inlet diameter), this area would be of a semi circular shape (like in the original post) and its area can be outlined by the diameter of the air intake - resulting in a shape similar to that in the original post. However, I am struggling to think how this same logic to calculate the area can be applied when the air intake diameter is less than the engine diameter and therefore results in a cone/hemisphere like shape.

Comment: @Zack.  Ok, let's explain it this way. The air enters the engine fan at about Mach 0.4. So, if the aircraft is slower than that, it's sucking air in. The area it's sucking from starts of being as large as in the diagram, and shaped like a hemisphere.  But as the speed increase, the air the engine wants is now starting to be provided by the forward motion, so the engine only has to draw air in from a smaller hemisphere. So, as the plane accelerates from stationary, the hemisphere shrinks. Once the plane reaches Mach 0.4, it basically just swallows the air that sits in front of the engine.

Comment: @Zack. So, the area of air the engine is acting upon is basically zero. Now, as the plane increases speed further, the air is effectively decelerating into the intake, not accelerating any more. Now the forward speed is providing more air than the engine wants, the diameter of the cylinder of air in front of the engine which is being swallowed reduces in diameter. The inlet is spilling air, and the engine is actually pushing some air away, or out of the intake. The air slows down as it enters the intake, and there is a ram air pressure rise in the intake. Hope that helps.